# table with only totals in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In quicksight I am trying to display the totals of some columns in a table without showing the records.

I have the following data

| ID | Price | Discount | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 10 | 60 |
| 1001 | 200 | 20 | 120 |
| 1002 | 1000 | 100 | 600 |
| 1003 | 2000 | 200 | 1200 |

I want to create a table that shows:
|Price|Discount|Cost|
|----|----|----|
|3300|330|1980|

How can I can do that? I have tried with showing totals in tables but the detail rows keep showing in the table

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "Pivot table" visualization instead of "Table", so that the metrics accumulate.